# OpenShift Service Account Permissions to Read Pod and Deployment Status

Tags: api, permissions, openshift

I would like to use the OpenShift REST api to make queries from a separate portal. We first created a service account using the following steps (where my-id is an admin in the project):

```
C:\openshift>oc login
Authentication required for https://openshift-test.foo.com:8443 (openshift)
Username: my-id
Password:
Login successful.

You have access to the following projects and can switch between them with 'oc project <projectname>':

  * datalake-replication-consumers
    datalake-replication-demo

Using project "datalake-replication-consumers".

C:\openshift>oc create serviceaccount gmi-registry
serviceaccount "gmi-registry" created

C:\openshift>oc policy add-role-to-user admin system:serviceaccounts:datalake-replication-consumers:gmi-registry
role "admin" added: "system:serviceaccounts:datalake-replication-consumers:gmi-registry"

C:\openshift>oc serviceaccounts get-token gmi-registry
<token here>
```

I then pasted that token as a bearer token into Postman to make a few api calls. Since I added my service account to the admin role within my project, I assumed this would work, but instead we're getting back a 403.

GET pods:

`https://openshift-test.foo.com:8443/api/v1/namespaces/datalake-replication-consumers/pods`

Response:

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:datalake-replication-consumers:gmi-registry\" cannot list pods in project \"datalake-replication-consumers\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "kind": "pods"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

GET specific deployment:

`https://openshift-test.foo.com:8443/oapi/v1/namespaces/datalake-replication-consumers/deploymentconfigs/entity-65869977-9d56-49a5-afa2-4a547df82d5c`

Response:

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "User \"system:serviceaccount:datalake-replication-consumers:gmi-registry\" cannot get deploymentconfigs in project \"datalake-replication-consumers\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "name": "entity-65869977-9d56-49a5-afa2-4a547df82d5c",
        "kind": "deploymentconfigs"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

What are we missing for service account permissions here?

**UDPATE**: I should also add that I pulled my own bearer token out of the CLI and used that for both calls. That worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very exciting answer, but our problem was solved when we installed a v3.7 instance. My initial tests were on v1.5, which I think corresponds to 3.5 or 3.6 in the enterprise offering?

Comment: Troubleshooting authentication issues like these can be done digging through your /var/log/messages, on the master nodes. FYI.